# Coercivity of functional vs Boundness of the set: how to prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, coercive

Referring to my previous question: [Two theorems of existence of a minimizer in a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151551/two-theorems-of-existence-of-a-minimizer-in-a-hilbert-space/4151590?noredirect=1#comment8605222_4151590).

I am trying to prove that the coercivity of the functional allow us to skip the hypothesis of boundness on the set $C$.

Could someone please give me a refernece or help me with the proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: if $J$ is coercive then the set $\{ x : J(x)\le M\}$ is bounded for all $M$.

Comment: Despite you hint, I am still not able to prove it, sorry.